# How to get control over skeleton of a GLB model in THREE.JS?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, skeletal-mesh, react-three-drei

I have generated an avatar, In glb format. But when I render the same the hands are stretched out. The model has a skeleton. But how do I get access to the skeleton such that I can bring its hands down or make the person sit on a chair etc? The technology I am using is THREE.js with react, react-three-fiber,react-three-drei, etc

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bdmrg4oc/1/   if you want to do more complex actions
(like siting) i suggest making animations in an animation program like blender and then importing them

```
    const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/gltf/Soldier.glb', function ( gltf ) {

        const model = gltf.scene;
        
        rightArm = model.getObjectByName( 'mixamorigRightArm' );

        scene.add( model );

    } );
```

`rightArm.rotation.z += Math.sin( t ) * 0.005;`